# How add email notification in Travis and where?

Tags: build, push-notification, continuous-integration, travis-ci, git-commit

I wanted to add email notification for me and my colleagues for Travis CI Build.
Whatever the result is failure or Sucess of Build we should get notified.
Should i need some extra settings in my git account?
What to add for email notification in Travis and where?I mean any file or i can add in .travis.yml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added email-notification to .travis.yml file in repository

```
notifications:  
  email:  
    recipients:  
    - xyz@abc.com  
    on_success: always  
    on_failure: always
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, just adding a possible pitfall when you have multiple e-mail addresses and you don't receive an e-mail notification:

Travis CI only sends build notifications to email addresses registered on GitHub. **If you have multiple addresses registered** you can set the email address for a specific repository using git:

> Note that this also changes the commit email address, not just the
>   Travis CI notification settings.

```
git config user.email "mynewemail@example.com"
```

Or set the email for all of your git repositories:

```
git config --global user.email "mynewemail@example.com"
```

Note that we currently don’t respect the detailed notifications settings on GitHub, as they’re not exposed via an API at this point.

Official documentation: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Configuring-email-notifications